# Error while sending a JSON object as message on kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am a student trying to learn about apache kafka.
I am trying to send a JSON object as a message using kafka in spring boot using java.
But as I try to send it,it throws an error saying that my model class cannot be cast to a string even though i have mentioned the Json serializer in application.properties file.
The exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.demo.model.BookES cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.example.demo.model.BookES is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

My application.properties file is

```
server.port=8081

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=myGroup
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

My controller class where i am trying to send my message

```
@PostMapping("/publish")
    public ResponseEntity<String> publish(@RequestBody BookES bookES){
        logger.info("in publish method");
        kafkaProducer.sendMessage(bookES);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Json message sent to kafka topic");
    }
```

My Kafka producer class which has the sendMessage method:

```
package com.example.demo.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.controller.BookController;
import com.example.demo.model.Book;
import com.example.demo.model.BookES;

@Service
public class KafkaProducer {
    
    @Autowired
    private NewTopic topic;
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);
    
    private String topicName = "bookmanagement";
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, BookES> kafkaTemplate;

    
    
    public void sendMessage(BookES bookES) {
        
        logger.info("in sendMessage method");
        logger.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s",bookES.toString()));
        
        Message<BookES> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(bookES).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topic.name()).build();
        kafkaTemplate.send(message);
        
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

My model class:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Document(indexName="my-application")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class BookES{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BookES [bookId=" + bookId + ", bookName=" + bookName + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
    @Id
    private String bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String description;
    public String getBookId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.bookId;
    }
    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }
    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public void setBookId(String bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    
}
```

my project is on the github link: [github link](https://github.com/chinmaygd02/Spring_boot_microservice_communication/tree/master)

I tried anotating my model class with with different annotations like @JsonSerializer,etc.. but with no success.
The response i got on postman on trying to post is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-11-22T11:24:30.738+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Can't convert value of class com.example.demo.model.BookES to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer",
    "path": "/books/publish"
}
```

Comment: Your configuration looks correct; check the INFO log for the producer config to make sure the right serializer is being used; your project is too big to ask someone to help (needs mongodb etc). Create a stripped-down [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can more easily see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own serializer that can serialize your `BookES` into byte array. Here is a class I use as generic Json serializer. It should handle your class just fine:

```
package ***;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.mgnt.utils.JsonUtils;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

    @Component
    public class GenericJsonSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {
        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(String s, Object obj) {
            byte[] result;
            try {
                result = JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(obj).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new SerializationException("Error occurred while serializing " + obj.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " to byte[]", e);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

In your properties you will need to register this class as your deserializer. Note that when you read your message back, if you want it to be read as `BookES` class you will need to provide deserializer class that would take byte array and convert it back into class `BookES`. (You will have to implement `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` interface). In my example I used class `JsonUtils` that comes from Open Source Java library MgntUtils (written and maintained by me). You can easily replace it and just use `ObjectMapper` class from Json-Jackson library or use GSON library. But It might make it simpler to use `JsonUtils`. If you wish to use it here is the [Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The MgntUtils library could be obtained as [Maven Artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on The [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)